# Selecting data from multiple rows from a temporary table create by SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query which is somehow broken:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID, TEST, CHR, NUMBER
    FROM Test_Table 
    JOIN ...
    WHERE ...
) TEMP_TABLE
FROM TEMP_TABLE a
LEFT
JOIN TEMP_TABLE b
  ON b.test = a.test 
 AND b.chr = 'x'
WHERE a.number IN (5,6)
 AND b.id IS NULL
GROUP
  BY a.test
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

From the first `FROM` statement I get the following temporary table:

```
 ID    , TEST,  CHR   ,  NUMBER
 ------------------------------
( 1    ,    7 , 'C'   ,       5),
( 2    ,    7 , 'T'   ,       6),
( 3    ,    8 , 'C'   ,       4),
( 4    ,    8 , 'T'   ,       5),
( 5    ,    9 , 'A'   ,       4),
( 6    ,    9 , 'G'   ,       5),
( 7    ,   10 , 'T'   ,       4),
( 8    ,   10 , 'A'   ,       5),
( 9    ,   10 , 'X'   ,       6),
(10    ,   14 , 'T'   ,       4),
(11    ,   14 , 'G'   ,       5);
```

From `FROM TEMP_TABLE ...` I try to implement the following conditions:

1. For example `test` column 7 contains two rows, if the `number` column contains values 5 AND 6, AND the value is NOT  **X** in the `chr` column, I would like to select select the rows with 7 in the `test` column.
2. For example `test` column 10 contains three rows, if the `number` column contains values 5 AND 6, AND the value **X** exists in the `chr` column, I would like to exclude rows with 10 in the `test` column.

As result it should only be `test` column with 7, because `test` column 7 have 5 and 6 in the `number` column and not X.

Result example:

```
ID | TEST | CHR  |  NUMBER               
1  |  7   |  C   |    5        
2  |  7   |  T   |    6
```

What did go wrong with the above SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has two `FROM` clauses remove one and try like below

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID, TEST, CHR, NUMBER
    FROM Test_Table 
    JOIN ...
    WHERE ...
)  a
LEFT JOIN 
 (
    SELECT ID, TEST, CHR, NUMBER
    FROM Test_Table 
    JOIN ...
    WHERE ...
)  b
  ON b.test = a.test 
 AND b.chr = 'x'
WHERE a.number IN (5,6)
 AND b.id IS NULL
GROUP
  BY a.test
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

A easier way to do this is to create a `TEMPORARY` table using `TEMPORARY` keyword like mentioned [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE (ID int, TEST varchar(100), CHR char, NUMBER int ); 

INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
 (SELECT ID, TEST, CHR, NUMBER
FROM Test_Table 
JOIN ...
WHERE ...);


SELECT *
FROM TEMP_TABLE a
LEFT
JOIN TEMP_TABLE b
  ON b.test = a.test 
 AND b.chr = 'x'
WHERE a.number IN (5,6)
 AND b.id IS NULL
GROUP
  BY a.test
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```